# Is there a relation between $\sqrt{x+ia}$ and $\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a relation between $\sqrt{x+ia}$ and $\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}$

where $a>0$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Thank you

Comment: Put $z=x+ia$. Then $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x$ is the sum of the geometric and arithmetic means of $z$ and its conjugate.

Comment: what it means? what i must write please

Comment: @almagest we can't have equality between the two ,

Comment: Your last try of the now deleted question was near, you had to change a $2$ to $\sqrt{2}$. For a general solution see Abramowitz/Stegun 3.7.27, 
http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_17.htm. Their $r$ is your $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}.$

Comment: @gammatester idon't find 3.2.27

Comment: Sorry I have already corrected it to 3.7.27, the page is correct.

Comment: @gammatester what is the relation between z and r please

Comment: I do not know what you mean. Their notation is standard, $z=x+iy,\,r=|z|$, they give the formula for $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{x+iy}$. You have chosen the unusual $a$ for the imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

By curiosity, let us evaluate the square root of $x+ia$, let $u+iv$.

Then

$$(u+iv)^2=u^2-v^2+i2uv=x+ia$$ which is equivalent to

$$x=u^2-v^2,\\a=2uv.$$

Then

$$xu^2=u^4-u^2v^2=u^4-\frac{a^2}4.$$

The solution in $u^2$ of the biquadratic equation is

$$u^2=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}2.$$

Do you see the relation ?

Comment: no, not yet i don't see

Comment: i don't see what is  $u$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Defined at the top.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly by a relation between $A=\sqrt{x+ia}$ and $B=\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}$ ?

Anyway, a relation easily obtained is 
$$B^2-A^2=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-ia$$

Do you want maybe a relation as $F(A,B)=0$ in which neither $a$ nor $x$ occur?